# Extruding around 3d cursor

Tags: 3d-cursor, extrude

Is there a way to extrude around 3d cursor like this
[image]

I know about spin but that doesn't serve my purpose.
Or any other way to do it with accuracy.

Comment: Spin does exactly that.  Why doesn't it suit your purpose?

Comment: Yes, spin looks like what you are looking for, you could try Bridge edge loops but it will create a linear connection between the too edge loops, and that doesn't look like what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the Blender element you want to extrude, and set the pivot point to "3D cursor". Extrude press the escape key, and use the rotate transform to complete the action.